# Internal android error causes Spinner.setUpChild to crash my app

Tags: android, android-spinner

For some time now I have detected a bug in Crashlytics that crashes my application. It has something to do with Spinners, but it doesn't seem to be a bug caused by bad programming, as no lines of my code are flagged.
It seems to be an internal error in the construction of the Spinners, but I can't get any information from anywhere.
Here is the stack-trace of the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:793)
    android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:777)
    android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:721)
    android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:683)
    android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
    android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1062)
    android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3140)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2201)
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9000)
    android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
    android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
    android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:729)
    android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```